# PHP post form not sending name="foo[]" data to $POST variable

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

I have this code to populate rows of a table in a php form

```
$html = '<tr>'; 
            $html .= '<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="exam_date_input[]" value="' . $exam_date . '"></td>';
            $html .= '<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="exam_code_input[]" value="' . $exam_code . '"></td>';
            $html .= '<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="exam_title[]" value="' . $title . '"></td>';
            $html .= '<td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="exam_time_input[]" value="' . $exam_time . '"></td>';
            $html .= "<td class='tg-yw4l'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='row_remove'> - </a></td>";
$html .= '<tr>';
die($html);
```

This is HTML is shown when I inspect the element

`<input name="exam_date_input[]" value="01/03/2017" type="text">`

Submitting the form should, in theory, add this array to the $POST array.

This isn't happening however.

Instead this code on my form action page `$date = $_POST['exam_date_input'];` gives the following notice:

`Notice: Undefined index: exam_date_input`

And there isn't an array of `exam_date_input` in the $POST array using `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: How is this form being submitted?  That `die()` command implies that this is *the entirety* of your HTML, which means there is no actual form.  What are you even submitting?

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` show you? There won't be a `$_POST['exam_date_input']` given those inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` is not inside the `form`, hence when you post the `form`, your `input` is not added to the parameters. The `die` seems to be incorrect, since you need to close the opened tags, including the `body` and the `html`. The solution is to make sure that you do not close the `form` before the `input`, but after your whole `table` and to use `echo` instead of `die`.

Comment: I had added some `div` tags within the form for styling purposes. This had caused the `input` fields within the `table` to appear outside the form. Changing the HTML markup has fixed this.

Comment: @IanButler if my answer solved your problem, then don't forget to mark it as the correct answer. If not, then please edit your question with the HTML you currently have and led me know about it.

Comment: I've put it as correct as it made me look at my code in the correct way. I probably didn't phrase the question very well though. It is tricky when there is so much different code going on to post the relevant pieces...